# Export IEnumerable object To Docx File (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export

We are using Kendo Grid for listing and needs to export record with filter to doc/Docx file.

Does Any one has idea about how to export IEumarable object to Doc/Docx file.

Here Code Snippet:

```
public FileResult ExportToWord([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
     IEnumerable rows = dtView.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
     MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
     workbook.Write(output);
     return File(output.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-word", "GridExcelExport.doc");
}
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = db.Studentrecord.ToList();
gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.doc");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
Response.Charset = string.Empty;

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
}
```